# Add two arrays without using the concat method

Tags: javascript

Here is a sample of what I would like to do

```
function test(r){
  var arr = ['d','e','f'];
  r.push(arr);
  /*
  More Code
  */
  return r;
}
var result = test(['a','b','c']);
alert(result.length);//I want this to alert 6
```

What I need to do is pass in an array and attach other arrays to the end of it and then return the array.  Because of passing by reference I cannot use `array.concat(array2);`.  Is there a way to do this without using something like a for loop to add the elements one by one.  I tried something like `r.push(arr.join());` but that did not work either.  Also, I would like the option of having objects in the arrays so really the `r.push(arr.join());` doesn't work very well.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
>>> var x = [1, 2, 3], y = [4, 5, 6];
>>> x.push.apply(x, y) // or Array.prototype.push.apply(x, y)
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Alternatively using [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) you can now do this

```
//generate a new array
a=[...x,...y];
//or modify one of the original arrays
x.push(...y);
```

Comment: Interesting use of `apply` to push all members of an array onto another array +1

Comment: I had seen the apply method before, but never really understood it (note to self need to study up on apply), but it certainly makes a concise way of doing what I wanted.  How does the second method differ from the first one though?  Using the Array.prototype instead of x.push.apply.

Comment: Both are equivalent. Calling `x.push(y)` means "call the function `x.push` with scope `x` and the arguments `[y]`. In this case `x.push` resolves to `Array.prototype.push`, thus: `Array.prototype.push.apply(x, [y])`. I only mentioned the second form as it's sometimes preferable to only reference `x` once.

Comment: `x.push.apply(x, y)` solved it for me, especially the second `x` even though I don't understand why it's like that

Answer (score 2):

```
function test(r){
  var _r = r.slice(0), // copy to new array reference
      arr = ['d','e','f'];

  _r = _r.concat(arr); // can use concat now

  return _r;
}
var result = test(['a','b','c']);
alert(result.length); // 6
```

Comment: Wrong, the array you return is not the modified array that was passed to the function, it is a copy

Answer (score 1):

This is [emulbreh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240335/add-two-arrays-without-using-the-concat-method/5240366#5240366), I'm just posting the test I did to verify it.
All credit should go to emulbreh

```
// original array
var r = ['a','b','c'];

function test(r){
  var arr = ['d','e','f'];
  r.push.apply(r, arr);

  /*
  More Code
  */
  return r;
}
var result = test( r );
console.log( r ); // ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
console.log( result === r ); // the returned array IS the original array but modified
```