# How to update an object property array value?

Tags: javascript

If I have an object defined as:

```
var myObj={};
```

Then, I update this object with:

```
myObj['fruit']=['apple', 'orange'];
```

Later, I would like to append "*[banana, melon]*" to `myObj['fruit']`, that's update `myObj` to

```
['apple','orange','banana','melon']
```

what is the most elegant way to update 'fruit' attribute value of myObj in my case? That's update array by appending a new array.

**--------EDIT-------**

**I need a way to append array as one variable, not extract each element of the appended array and push.** e.g. `oldArray` append with `newArray = final array`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Newbie Javascript : appending to array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351409/newbie-javascript-appending-to-array)

Comment: Very elegant: Use Apply:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240335/add-two-arrays-without-using-the-concat-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript has a built in [`Array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

```
myObj["fruit"].push( 'banana', 'melon' );
```

There are a few ways to approach appending an array.  First up, use [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to call push with the array as individual arguments:

```
var toAppend = ['banana', 'melon'];
// note [].push is just getting the "push" function from an empty array
// the first argument to "apply" is the array you are pushing too, the
// second is the array containing items to append
[].push.apply( myObj["fruit"], toAppend );
```

Also, you could [`concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) the arrays, however concat doesn't modify the original array so if you have other references they might get lost:

```
myObj["fruit"] = myObj["fruit"].concat( toAppend );
```

Comment: So, the updated final array can be got by myObj['fruit'] = [].push.apply( myObj["fruit"], toAppend ); I guess.

Comment: If you are using push, it returns the new length of the array or the # of items added... `push()` affects the array it is pushing to, so you don't need to assign it to anything...

Comment: mplungjan's proposal is also great: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240335/add-two-arrays-without-using-the-concat-method

Comment: @Leem - That suggests `.push.apply()` just like the second section of my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to push, then [concat](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp) :)

Comment: Better reference: [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to iterate the array items that you want to push, by doing this:

```
var newObj = ["banana", "melon"];

for (var i in newObj)
{
   myObj['fruit'].push(newObj[i]);
}
```

:)

Comment: Looping arrays with `for ... in` is a bad idea... Better to iterate `for (var i=0, l=array.length, i<l, i++)`

Comment: can you expand your opinion about this for ... in? i cant see any problem with it

Comment: Properties added to the `Array.prototype` will show up when you `for ... in` -- Although altering these prototypes isn't the best idea, it is done do do things like filling in `.indexOf()` or other newer array functions that don't exist across all browsers... See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/gnarf/YjVQY/ --- Because of this you should **NEVER** use `for ... in` on arrays, considering they have lengths and numeric properties...

Comment: ah ok, that is applicable if we add a new prototype... well, maybe i should start to use your way. nice sharing! :)

Comment: Also, FYI - generally, any uses of a `for ... in` should also use [`.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)