# Merge 2 arrays without using concat()

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add two arrays without using the concat method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240335/add-two-arrays-without-using-the-concat-method)

I want to merge 2 arrays in javascript without using the concat() function.

Im trying to do it with push and `indexOf`

but its not working maybe im typing it wrong `array1.push(indexOf(array2))`.

Comment: And why exactly can't you use concat().

Comment: Merge and concatenate are not necessarily the same terms...

Answer (score 2):

From [Add two arrays without using the concat method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240335/add-two-arrays-without-using-the-concat-method)

```
>>> var x = [1, 2, 3], y = [4, 5, 6];
>>> x.push.apply(x, y) // or Array.prototype.push.apply(x, y)
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Linking a duplicate question and the copy/pasta is not an answer.  You should delete this.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through array2 and push items in array1.

```
for(var k=0; k < array2.length; k++){

    array1.push(array2[k]);
}
```

if you don't want to modify array1. create new array.

```
var merged_array = [];
    for(var k=0; k < array1.length; k++){    
        merged_array .push(array2[k]);
    }

   for(var k=0; k < array2.length; k++){    
        merged_array .push(array2[k]);
    }
console.log(merged_array );
```