# Why can't I concat an array reference in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

I have two arrays, one comes as a reference (parameter) from a function, and the other is created as part of the function - exactly the same scenario as described here:

[Add two arrays without using the concat method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240335/add-two-arrays-without-using-the-concat-method)

I was using the push.apply() method as per the suggestion above, but can someone please explain to me, why I can't use concat() to merge two arrays if the array is sent into the function as a reference?

Comment: Have a look at the link. It doesn't matter what I do, it's exactly the same as shown on the other page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Refer to [Array.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) on MDN:

> Any operation on the new array *will have no effect on the original arrays*, and vice versa.

This makes it behave *differently* from `Array.push.apply` which *will* mutate the original Array object - the return value of `Array.concat` must be used. Otherwise, it works as explained in the MDN link above.

Comment: It also states that "Object references (and not the actual object): concat copies object references into the new array. Both the original and new array refer to the same object. That is, if a referenced object is modified, the changes are visible to both the new and original arrays."

Comment: @Tamas That is talking about the *objects in* the arrays, not the arrays themselves - but, yes.

Answer (score 10):

If you use `concat` the original array will be *unmodified*. If you have a reference to it you wont see the new elements.

```
var arr1 = [ "a", "b" ];
var arr2 = [ "c", "d" ];
arr1.push.apply(arr1, arr2);
```

Basically does this:

```
[ "a", "b" ].push("c", "d");
```

`apply` turns an array into a list of arguments. The first argument to `apply` is the `context` by the way, `arr1` in this case since you want the push to apply to `arr1`.

You can use `concat`:

```
var arr1 = [ "a", "b" ];
var arr2 = [ "c", "d" ];
var arr3 = arr1.concat(arr2);
```

This leaves the original `arr1` as it was. You've created a new array that has both `arr1` and `arr2` elements in it. If you have a reference to the original `arr1` it will be *unmodified*. That might be a reason to not want to use `concat`.

Comment: I won't be able to accept 2 answers but this was helpful as well Frits, thank you!

Comment: Does this require Array.prototype or can it be done with just an array?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have 2 arrays "a" and "b". `Array.concat` method will **return** new instance of `Array` "c" which represents concatenation between a and b **without any mutation of a or b**. `Array.push` **return** last index of pushed element and mutate **`this`** instance.


Since ES6 (or 15, not sure) it's possible to unpack parameters and you can use push to concatenate (without harmful code) as well

```
a = [1,2,3,4]; // a=[1,2,3,4];
b = [5,6,7,8]; // b=[5,6,7,8]; 
a.push(...b)   // a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]; b=[5,6,7,8]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful!